# Cannot connect to port 7

Tags: java, sockets, echo

Running the following code give exception:

> D:\books\tutorial\networking\sockets\examples>java EchoClient
>   Connection refused: connect

This is actually the code from java tutorials (from oracle)
I have even tried opening icmp eco requests from firewall,can anyone explain why this is happing?I am using windows 7 32 bit

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            echoSocket = new Socket("localhost", 7);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                                   new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;

    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine()); 
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
    echoSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Unix machines at any rate, you have to have superuser privileges (more or less equivalent to Administrator privileges on Windows) to open port numbers less than 1024 for listening.  You might well be running into the equivalent problem on Windows. On the other hand, a closer look at the code suggests that you are trying to connect to it as a client, which should not require elevated privileges.

Maybe the trouble is that there is no service (daemon) listening on the port - so there is nothing to respond to your echo request?

Comment: hey i read somewhere that port 7 is echo port ,and i have even tried adding the firewall exception but still its not workin

Comment: I've modified my answer - maybe the trouble is that you don't have an echo service configured.

Comment: Yeah, nowadays servers are running only needed services. You can use [nmap](http://nmap.org/) to see whether a port is open.

Comment: @lol - you have to create an echo server and set it up running on some port ;)

Comment: to this example si given at javatutorial's website but the thing is they have nowhere mentioned how to truobleshoot...

Comment: @lol: I can spell Windows - U.N.I.X, right?  There might be an echo service available; but I'm not sure how you'd go about configuring it.  If you decide to create your own, then you may run into the problem in my initial diagnosis.